# Transformers and double strike

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I was attacking with a Transformers card that, on combat damage to a player transforms but said creature has double strike, will the creature deal first strike damage, convert and then deal regular damage with its converted side?

Comment: Please include the exact card you're referring to; you can use the `[mtg:CARDNAME]` syntax to link to Gatherer. (It won't show up in the preview, don't worry about that)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the creature would Convert (or Transform) before dealing the double-strike damage in the regular damage step.

From a ruling on [Blitzwing, Cruel Tormentor](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Blitzwing%2C%20Cruel%20Tormentor):

> After Blitzwing, Adaptive Assailant converts into Blitzwing, Cruel Tormentor, it's still an attacking creature in combat. It will still have any gained abilities, including the ability it gained at the beginning of combat. **Notably, if it has somehow gained double strike, it will convert before dealing combat damage in the regular combat damage step**.

This is because first strike damage and regular damage are separate combat damage steps, with triggered abilities being resolved between them.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is "Probably, it depends" There are three possible cases here, in order of increasing likelihood:

- The creature blinks (exile and return transformed) when it transforms.
- The creature transformed in place but no longer has double strike.
- The creature transformed in place and what was giving it double strike is still there.

The first case here here isn't likely. While there are many cards that exile and return transformed, none of them trigger on combat damage, and only those that meld are creatures on both sides. Assuming you mean the Transformers card (BOT set) that convert, none of them including the 8 that can do so on combat damage exile to transform. If this did happen, the newly entered creature wouldn't even be attacking, and would not be part of combat.

The second is a bit of an edge case, but possible. If double strike was printed only on the front face (like [Enduring Angel](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Enduring%20Angel) or the effect that gave double strike ended (say a soulbond with [Silverblade Paladin](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Silverblade%20Paladin) who died when it was blocked), then the creature would no longer have double strike, losing double strike after the first combat damage step means the creature will not do damage in the second combat damage step, per the Comprehensive Rules (emphasis mine):

> **702.4b** If at least one attacking or blocking creature has first strike (see rule 702.7) or double strike as the combat damage step begins, the only creatures that assign combat damage in that step are those with first strike or double strike. After that step, instead of proceeding to the end of combat step, the phase gets a second combat damage step. **The only creatures that assign combat damage in that step are the remaining attackers and blockers that had neither first strike nor double strike as the first combat damage step began**, as well as the remaining attackers and blockers that currently have double strike. After that step, the phase proceeds to the end of combat step.

The first case is by far the most likely, most transforming creatures don't blink when they transform, and effects granting abilities are tied to the object, not the specific form or face of that object, so if it had double strike from any ongoing effect like [Duelist's Heritage](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Duelist%27s%20Heritage), [Fireshrieker](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Fireshrieker) or [Boros Charm](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Boros%20Charm) will still have double strike and still deal combat damage.

Comment: I feel like the second case listed is pretty irrelevant to the question; transforming doesn't play into the rules in any way there; it's just explaining that a creature that loses double strike after the first combat damage step will not deal its damage in the second combat damage step. It didn't lose double strike as a result of transforming. In other words, if you include that, why not also include the situation where the transformed creature is killed by an instant after the first combat damage step, or any other number of things that could prevent it from dealing the double-strike damage?

Comment: @GendoIkari The question being asked at all implies that the card is still in play during the second combat damage step. While you are correct there are a lot of things that could otherwise prevent the creature from doing damage, most of them are ruled out by context, these are the only possibilities left ambiguous by the question asked.

Comment: Sure, but the creature could just as easily lose double-strike due to Humble, etc.I think the important thing to note is that transforming does not make the creature lose double-strike, and there's no edge case where it does. The core of the question was "does transforming make a creature lose double-strike or remove it from combat". Feels like it complicates the issue to mention that other unrelated things could cause it to lose double strike.

Comment: The card [mtg:Enduring Angel] has double strike printed on its front face but not its back face, and it could transform after damage is dealt in the first strike combat damage step. So, that is a situation that is practically equivalent to the second bullet point here, where the transformation is directly relevant. You could reword it as "The creature transformed in place but it no longer has double strike."